# Lost Public and Private Keys and no access to marketplace

Tags: magento2, marketplace

We installed M2 via a one Click installer. We were not supplied with access keys. We would like to use the marketplace now. Is there a way to get those keys without access to Magento Marketplace? I can't log in to reset them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign in to Magento Marketplace to get your access keys.

Maybe someone in the Magento Community Engineering Slack Channel #marketplace can help you with regaining access to your account.